Why does the Clifford Group have order $2^{n+1}$?
I'm studying Barry Simon's book on representation theory for my final project. There's a section where he introduces the Clifford Group and states that it has order $2^n$, which I can't seem to find an easy way to prove.
He first introduces the Clifford Algebra as a set of $n$ complex square matrices $\gamma_1,...,\gamma_n$ such that
$$\gamma_i \gamma_j + \gamma_j \gamma_i = 2\delta_{ij}\mathbb{I}.$$
He then introduces the Clifford Group, which we can think of as the group generated by the symbols $\gamma_1,...,\gamma_n$. The anticommutation relation makes it so that each element is represented by an ordered subset of $\{1,...,n\}$ and a sign $\pm 1$. We can think of each element as any of the possible ordered products of $\gamma_{i1},...,\gamma_{i_k}$. The multiplication rule is simply determined by ordering each $\gamma_j$ using anticommutivity until we either get $\gamma_j^2 = \mathbb{I}$ or $\gamma_j$ is ordered, and accounting for the sign.
With this approach, that is, thinking the $\gamma_i$ are just different symbols, I understand that the Clifford group has order $2^{n+1}$, since there are $2^n$ possible ordered subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$ and two signs. The point is I'm trying to prove that, when the $\gamma_j$ are actually matrices, that is, when representing the Clifford group,  there are still $2^{n+1}$ elements. This means that any of the possible products are different from any other product or element (or that the representation is injective). There's some arguments that I can find using commutation relations that prove this partially, but there's no clear argument that I can find to prove this easily and completely. Does anyone see clearly why the order is $2^{n+1}$?
I feel I'm missing something since this question is omitted in Simon's text. I'm attaching a capture of the book in the following link.
Thank your for your time.
Simon's defintion of the Clifford Group

If you want prove it purely from this definition, this is what I would do: define a symmetric bilinear form on the Clifford algebra $(X,Y)\mapsto\mathrm{tr(XY)}$. Prove that this form is nondegenerate. Now prove the "positive" Clifford group elements are orthogonal with respect to this form. This proves they are linearly independent, and by definition they also span, so they form a basis.

Alternatively, you can recognize that this definition gives you the universal property of Clifford algebras. This property proves that $Cl(V\oplus W) \cong Cl(V)\mathbin{\hat\otimes}Cl(W)$ when $V,W$ are orthogonal subspaces. Prove that $\dim Cl(V) = 2$ when $\dim V = 1$. Now break your total space $V$ up into a direct sum of orthogonal 1D spaces by choosing an orthogonal basis. This proves $\dim Cl(V) = 2^{\dim V}$.

Dear @Nicholas. Thank you for your quick answer. Regarding your first response, I do not understand what is accomplished by proving the anticommuting elements form a basis. After all, I'm looking foward to the fact that their matrix product as a group yields $2^{n+1}$ different elements. If they form a basis, then any product is a linear combination of basis elements but I can't still figure out why that would mean they're different. I apologize since my knowledge of algebras is very little, which is why I prefer to work directly with the defintion.

Because they form a basis you know that all the products $\gamma_{i_1}\dotsc\gamma_{i_k}$ with $1\leq i_1<\dotsb<i_k\leq n$ are distinct. Then it's trivial that multiplying one such product by another gives $\pm$ another such product, so these are the only elements of the group. Thus it's order is $2^{n+1}$.

Any other way of proving that $\gamma_{i_1}\dotsb\gamma_{i_k} = \gamma_{j_1}\dotsb\gamma_{j_l}$ iff $k = l$ and $i_1=j_1,\dotsc,i_k=j_k$ where $1\leq i_1<\dotsb<i_k\leq n$ and $1\leq j_1<\dotsb<j_l\leq n$ would also work.

Dear @NicholasTodoroff. Thanks for the answers. Finally, I have gone for the following argument, which I believe makes sense. First, we can prove that $Tr(\gamma_A)=0$ for every nonempty subset $A\subset {1,\ldots,n}$. This is because $Tr(\gamma_A) = \pm Tr(\gamma_j \gamma_A \gamma_j)$. So, if $A \neq B$ suppose $\gamma_A = \pm \gamma_B$, then by multiplying $Tr(\gamma_A^2) = Tr(\gamma_{A\triangle B})$, but one is $\pm 1$ and the other is $0$ since $A\triangle B$ is nonempty. Then it has to be $A=B$, as you suggested.

I don't understand how you start from $$Tr(\gamma_A) = \pm Tr(\gamma_j\gamma_A\gamma_j)$$ and conclude $$Tr(\gamma_A) = 0.$$

My bad, it only works when $\gamma_A = -\gamma_j \gamma_A \gamma_j$, which is when $|A|$  is odd, then you just take traces and use $Tr(AB)=Tr(BA)$ to get $Tr(\gamma_A)=-Tr(\gamma_A)$. I would need to prove that the trace is $0$ in the case that $|A|$ is even.

Ah, I see. You also run into a (potentially navigable) corner case with $A = {1,\dotsc,n}$.

You're right. It turns out that taking the Pauli matrices we get $\sigma_x \sigma_y \sigma_z = i\mathbb{I}$ which is not of trace $0$, so the statement that $Tr(\gamma_A) = 0$ is not true for every nonempty A.

Somewhat tangential, but I should clarify: when I was talking about trace in my first comment, what I meant was the "trace of multiplication". I.e., for every $x \in Cl(V)$, we define $\mathrm{tr}(x)$ as the trace of the linear transformation $m_x : Cl(V) \to Cl(V)$ where simply $m_x(y) = xy$. For this trace it is indeed the case that $\mathrm{tr}(\gamma_A) = 0$ for $A \ne \varnothing$.

I understand that is the case since if $A$ is nonempty then multiplying by $\gamma_A$ is a permutation based on the group product. This trace could work for my argument, but in order to prove tr$(\gamma_A) = 0$, I would first need to prove that the $\gamma_i$ form a basis for the vector space, as you suggested, right? Following this Wikipedia post, that would prove that the products are a basis for the algebra and then the trace of multiplication is 0 since I'm permuting basis elements.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
